# exporting XmlDocument to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmldocument

I have a XmlDocument in which i have hierarchical data and i want to export this data to excel. Please help me to get out of this.
I have tried to read this data into a dataset but it is not working for me.

Comment: DataSet ds = new DataSet();           
ds.ReadXml(new XmlNodeReader(taxonomyxml)); with this i am able to get data in data set but not in proper format

Answer (score 0):

Please send xml sample for more information.

Your code loads xml into dataset, so,
if your xml doesn't exported from DataSet, you could use LinqToXml.
for example:

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
    <title>Business Logic Toolkit for .NET</title>
    <link>http://www.bltoolkit.net</link>
    <description />
    <lastBuildDate>2009-01-11</lastBuildDate>
    <item>
        <title>Version 3.1 released</title>
        <link>http://www.bltoolkit.net/Download.htm</link>
        <description>See &lt;a href="http://www.bltoolkit.net/Download.htm"&gt;change log&lt;/a&gt;</description>
        <pubDate>2009-01-11</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Version 3.0 released</title>
        <link>http://www.bltoolkit.net/Download.htm</link>
        <description>See &lt;a href="http://www.bltoolkit.net/Download.htm"&gt;change log&lt;/a&gt;</description>
        <pubDate>2008-05-21</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>New examples</title>
        <link>http://www.bltoolkit.net/Doc/</link>
        <description>See the following &lt;a href="http://www.bltoolkit.net/Doc/"&gt;link&lt;/a&gt;</description>
        <pubDate>2008-05-10</pubDate>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

this code get all rss items title

```
var path = @"D:\rss.xml";
var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
rssTitles = doc.Root.Descendants("item").Elements("title").Select(el => el.Value);
```

results:

```
Version 3.1 released
Version 3.0 released
New examples
```

Comment: my xml document contains lage data but as a small snapshot see this

Comment: if your document larger then 10 MB I recommend to use simple `XmlReader`because LinqToXml or others are DOM parsers and could use much memory because they load all xml dom into memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Roles>
  <BalanceSheets RoleURL="http://fluor.com/role/BalanceSheets" RoleDefination="0020 - CONDENSED CONSOLIDATED BALANCE SHEET">
    <Taxonomys>
      <StatementOfFinancialPositionAbstract TaxonomyPresentationId="StatementOfFinancialPositionAbstract">
        <StatementLineItems TaxonomyPresentationId="StatementOfFinancialPositionAbstract">
          <LiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquityAbstract TaxonomyPresentationId="StatementLineItems">
            <CommitmentsAndContingencies TaxonomyPresentationId="LiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquityAbstract" />
            <OtherLiabilitiesNoncurrent TaxonomyPresentationId="LiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquityAbstract" />
            <NonRecourseProjectFinanceDebtNoncurrent TaxonomyPresentationId="LiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquityAbstract" />
            <LongTermDebtNoncurrent TaxonomyPresentationId="LiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquityAbstract" />
            <LiabilitiesCurrentAbstract TaxonomyPresentationId="LiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquityAbstract">
              <BillingsInExcessOfCost TaxonomyPresentationId="LiabilitiesCurrentAbstract" />
              <LiabilitiesCurrent TaxonomyPresentationId="LiabilitiesCurrentAbstract" />
              <AccountsPayable TaxonomyPresentationId="LiabilitiesCurrentAbstract" />
              <BridgeLoan TaxonomyPresentationId="LiabilitiesCurrentAbstract" />
              <NonRecourseProjectFinanceDebtCurrent TaxonomyPresentationId="LiabilitiesCurrentAbstract" />
              <EmployeeRelatedLiabilities TaxonomyPresentationId="LiabilitiesCurrentAbstract" />
              <OtherAccruedLiabilities TaxonomyPresentationId="LiabilitiesCurrentAbstract" />
              <ConvertibleDebtCurrent TaxonomyPresentationId="LiabilitiesCurrentAbstract" />
            </LiabilitiesCurrentAbstract>
          </LiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquityAbstract>
        </StatementLineItems>
      </StatementOfFinancialPositionAbstract>
    </Taxonomys>
  </BalanceSheets>
</Roles>
```